# Spring Session Redis failing to serialize OAuth2AccessToken

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-session

I'm trying to setup Spring session with Redis and I want data to be serialized to JSON.

This is my SessionConfig:

```java
@Configuration
public class SessionConfig implements BeanClassLoaderAware {

    @Value("${server.session.cookie.secure}")
    private Boolean useSecureCookie;

    private ClassLoader loader;

    @Bean
    public RedisSerializer<Object> springSessionDefaultRedisSerializer() {
        return new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer(objectMapper());
    }

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModules(SecurityJackson2Modules.getModules(this.loader));
        return mapper;
    }

    @Override
    public void setBeanClassLoader(ClassLoader classLoader) {
        this.loader = classLoader;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultCookieSerializer cookieSerializer() {
        DefaultCookieSerializer serializer = new DefaultCookieSerializer();
        serializer.setCookieName("SESSION");
        serializer.setCookiePath("/");
        serializer.setUseSecureCookie(Optional.ofNullable(useSecureCookie).orElse(false));
        return serializer;
    }

}
```

I'm getting this exception when logging in:

> org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Could not write JSON: Type id handling not implemented for type org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken (by serializer of type org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessTokenJackson2Serializer) (through reference chain: org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl["authentication"]->org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication["userAuthentication"]->org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken["principal"]->my.package.app.security.OAuth2Employee["accessToken"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Type id handling not implemented for type org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken (by serializer of type org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessTokenJackson2Serializer) (through reference chain: org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl["authentication"]->org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication["userAuthentication"]->org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken["principal"]->my.package.app.security.OAuth2Employee["accessToken"])

Java version 8
Spring boot version is 1.5.12.RELEASE
Spring Session and Spring Session Data Redis versions are both 1.3.5.RELEASE

Am I missing something in configuration?